# Set type for nested object in react using typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
Interface Button{
buttonTitle: {
    addAdmin?: string;
  confirmAdmin?: string;
  }
}
```

How I can define type for buttonTitle?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have anything to do with React. It's a TypeScript question.

Just define another `interface` (or `type` if that's your preference) and use it:

```js
interface ButtonTitle {
  addAdmin?: string;
  confirmAdmin?: string;
}

interface Button {
  buttonTitle: ButtonTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum type for this.

```
enum ButtonTitle {
  addAdmin = "ADDADMIN",
  confirmAdmin = "CONFIRMADMIN",
}

Interface Button {
  buttonTitle: ButtonTitle
}
```

You can read more about enums [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)